# What is the proper way to add a method to a built-in class in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, built-in-types

In [exercism.io](http://exercism.io) I have submitted a solution ot the [`Pangram Problem`](http://exercism.io/submissions/0db312ba068646f088c75c08b63f0c9a) in `Ruby`.

To solve the problem, I created a method for the `String` class called `alpha?` which determines if a character is alphabetial or not ('a'..'z'). This method is inside a **module** which I then **include** in the String class.

Here is my code:

```
module Str_Plus
  def alpha?
      self[/[a-zA-Z]+/] == self
  end
end

class Pangram
  String.include Str_Plus 
  ...
end
```

Someone mentioned this is **NOT the best way to add functionality to a built-in class**. 
My question is, **What is the proper way**?

Comment: check out my stab at the problem :) http://exercism.io/submissions/d8e23c0109f849e7b47de2bc20689e88

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You do `(str.downcase.chars.uniq.sort & alphabet) == alphabet`. Wouldn't `(alphabet & str.downcase.chars) == alphabet` work as well?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: indeed, you're right. You could have posted this on exercism as well :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Didn't want to create an account and learn how it works just for that.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: might as well solve some problems. :) I found the process to be akin to meditation. Interesting thoughts/ideas just pop into your head.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yeah, but not now. Plus I have accounts at a dozen or so similar sites already.

Comment: You needn't shout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tenebrousedge there was probably hinting at [refinements](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html).

Or, rather, not patching `String` at all. More often than not, monkeypatching creates more problems than it solves. What if String already knew `alpha?` and it did something different?

For example, future versions of ruby might add `String#alpha?` that will handle unicode properly

```
'新幹線'.alpha? # => true
```

and your code, as it is, would overwrite this built-in functionality with an inferior version. Now your app is breaking in all kinds of places, because stdlib/rails assumes the new behaviour. Chaos!

This is to say: avoid monkeypatching whenever possible. And when you **can't** avoid, use refinements.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add to @sergio's answer with a concrete what-to-do example (writing as an answer to get code formatting). Make your own class / module. A method like `alpha?` doesn't have to be defined on `String` itself to be useful and reusable, and putting it there, even with refinements, is asking for name collisions. Any gem that does this is immediately on my shit list, because it just takes two gems to choose the same name for a method they want to add and it's chaos.

Instead, better to keep your methods contained to your own classes. I'd choose a better name than `MyStringIdentifier`, but you don't have to

As a module:

```
module MyStringIdentifier
  # allows you to use `MyStringIdentifer.any_module_method_name_here`
  extend self

  def alpha?(string)
    !!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/ =~ string)
  end
end

MyStringIdentifier.alpha?("hello")
```

Or, as a class:

```
class MyStringIdentifier
  attr_reader :string

  def initialize(string)
    @string = string.to_s
  end

  def alpha?
    !!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/ =~ string)
  end
end

MyStringIdentifier.new("hello").alpha?
```

Comment: Threequals looks much better here: `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/ === string`. No need for any additional booleanification.

Comment: I like this, however what I am trying to accomplish is to add functionality to a built-in class in a controlled manner, that way I can achieve what I am trying to achieve while having a clean, elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

When extending a core class I like to add a `core_ext` directory in the `lib` directory.

Create and [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files) for loading the custom extensions (for example: `config/initializers/core_exts.rb`). And add the following line in it:

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "core_ext", "*.rb")].each {|file| require file }
```

and have your extension like:

```
#lib/core_ext/string.rb
class String
  def alpha?
    self[/[a-zA-Z]+/] == self
  end
end
```

now from the console you can do

```
"ABCD".alpha? # true
"ABC1".alpha? # false
"1234".alpha? # false
```

I hope that this helps

Comment: Folder organization is good, but as far as actual logic goes, this is worse than `include`, because it unconditionally overwrites the method, leaving no trace. With `include`, the module will be in the ancestors chain, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I will try to use more `includes` in my apps and less of the `core_ext`